# Web Scraping - Get information from Twitch.tv

Tags: java, android-studio, web-scraping

Hello I am making an application for android with Android Studio and Java.

I want to get a picture of a channel, the number of viewers, the game being streamed, and if possible the chat.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library. You will have the ability to extract and manipulate data in a website. You can do this by providing HTML attributes/element and then the library will parse the data for you.

For example, when you are watching a twitch stream, the attribute of the title of the stream is 'stream-title' which you can get using JSOUP.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you crawler4j as its matching with JAVA and Android. Have a look! https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j